# Toggle language by pressing Shift + Command

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

I've moved from PC to Mac and I'm used to pressing `Shift + Ctrl`, while on Mac I have to press `Ctrl + Space`. This is a bit frustrating (probably because I've only used it for 2 days), so I opened System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts and tried to change the shortcut to `Shift + Command` and for some reason it refuses to change.

I tried to test some other shortcuts such as `Command + Z` and it works fine. I'd still like to change it to `Shift + Command`. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: I don't think so, these are two modifier keys and are used in other shortcuts. For example `cmd` + `shift` + `tab`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With macOS' system shortcuts you can't set keyboards shortcuts solely using modifier keys.

You need to specify an additional (non-modifier) key for macOS to accept and save your shortcut.

Sierra does have an extra setting (in system prefs/keyboard/input sources) for switching between certain keyboards via Caps Lock alone, but that does not help solve your problem.

Comment: @TomGewecke True. It still does not map the shortcut to Shift + Cmd, as requested by OP, though.

Comment: you can use [CommandShift](https://github.com/VasylBaran/CommandShift) to switch language with Command + Shift

Answer (score 12):

With freshest version ([11.4.0](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/files/Karabiner-Elements-11.4.0.dmg) at 13.12.2017) of [Karabiner Elements](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) and `Cmd + e` for previous language source:

[image]

You can put this [json gist](https://gist.github.com/vsalex/eac8c27bc7cf428ba8e19671cdb34142) to `~/.config/karabiner/assets/complex_modifications/<filename>.json`, add gist rule in `Karabiner Elements Preferences -> Complex Modifications -> Rules -> Add rule` and Enable `Languages -> Command + Shift to Command + e`.

[image]

This will remap `Cmd + Shift` to `Cmd + e` and you can change language source by `Cmd + Shift`.

Comment: Does not work in Catalina, unfortunately.

Comment: worked for me Catalina 10.15.3, thank you!

Comment: Works on MacOs Mojave But it breaks command+shift+t in Chrome.

Answer (score 6):

[Punto Switcher](https://yandex.ru/soft/punto/) can do it. This utility helps with language auto toggling but you can disable this behaviour and just set desired key binding. I think it doesn't have UI other than Russian, but you will surely be able to configure it intuitively.

Comment: I think this should be marked as accepted answer since it literally does what it should without any "almost", thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I use [CommandShift](https://github.com/VasylBaran/CommandShift). It's a free and open-source app which "allows you to change input source using Windows-style shortcut (e.g. Command + Shift, Option + Shift, Control + Shift or Fn + Shift)"

Sounds like what you're looking for =)

Answer (score 2):

I also faced with this issue, so created a small tray application that will remap the default shortcut to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>:

[image]

Here is a link to the [GitHub](https://github.com/3t0n/LayoutSwitcher/releases).

Comment: It's a really nice idea.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to change the way to shift between languages from the default is as follows:

Open System Preferences and tap Keyboard:
[image: Press Keyboard from System Preferences]

Then tap Shortcuts, then from the side list tap "Input Sources", then "Select Next Source":
[image: ShortCuts > Input Sources > "select next source"]

*Note you will have to choose something like CNTRL-SHIFT-1 or another key combo than shift-space, but you can play around with it and find a combo that works for you.

**Edit:** If you want to do what you want by only pressing control shift, you might be able to do that by creating an applescript which toggles the languages and using a 3rd party hot key app on the appstore. I don't advise this, but it would be conceivably possible. For the sake of convenience, I have attached such an applescript that you can use for this purpose where if you map say control shift to this applescript, it will execute the CMD space code (or you can change it another code which doesn't conflict with spotlight (my personal recommendation):

```
tell application id "com.apple.systemevents"
keystroke (key code 49 using command down)
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use karabiner-elements with the following complex modification rule to change the input source with `left_control + left_shift`. It has been tested on macOS Sonoma 14.3.1.

```
{
  "from": {
    "key_code": "left_shift",
    "modifiers": {
      "mandatory": [
        "left_control"
      ]
    }
  },
  "to": [
    {
      "key_code": "left_shift",
      "modifiers": [
        "left_control"
      ],
      "lazy": true
    }
  ],
  "to_if_alone": [
    {
      "key_code": "spacebar",
      "modifiers": [
        "left_command"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "type": "basic"
},
```

With this rule, you can:

1. Press `left control + left shift` to change the input source.
2. Press `left control + left shift + any other key` to use the other shortcuts. This means that `left control + left shift` can still be modifier for other shortcuts.
3. Press `left shift` multiple times while holding down the `left control` to change multiple input source, just like pressing `space bar` multiple times while pressing the `command` key.

Please note:

1. You must set the shortcut to change the input source to `command + spacebar` for this rule to take effect.
2. Place your target shortcut key combination under the "to_if_alone" event, and create a shortcut key combination exactly like the original key combination under the "to" event so that you can use the original key combination as part of other shortcut keys.
3. Please set lazy to true under the "to" event to ensure that the "to" event will only be triggered when it is part of other shortcuts.
4. You can change `left_control` to `control` and `left_shift` to `shift` so that any combination of `control + shift` can take effect.

Source: https://github.com/res876ttb/mykarabiner/blob/main/karabiner_caps_lock_modifier.json#L458

Answer (score 0):

An improvement for the answer of [Raymond Hsu](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/469334/414935).

It will work only if you push <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> first and then <kbd>Shift</kbd> but if you push <kbd>Shift</kbd> first it will not work.

So I suggest the following config for [karabiner-elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/):

```
{
    "description": "Change input source",
    "manipulators": [
        {
            "from": {
                "key_code": "left_shift",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": [
                        "left_control"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "left_shift",
                    "lazy": true,
                    "modifiers": [
                        "left_control"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "to_if_alone": [
                {
                    "key_code": "spacebar",
                    "modifiers": [
                        "left_command"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        },
        {
            "from": {
                "key_code": "left_control",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": [
                        "left_shift"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "left_control",
                    "lazy": true,
                    "modifiers": [
                        "left_shift"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "to_if_alone": [
                {
                    "key_code": "spacebar",
                    "modifiers": [
                        "left_command"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        }
    ]
}
```