# How can I switch between language input sources using Alt-Shift on Catalina?

Tags: windows, catalina, input-source, text-input

I tried a couple of Karabiner scripts available online, but none is working.

Also, it looks like there is some confusion about what is <kbd>Alt</kbd> on mac keyboards. Although semantically, this is the <kbd>⌥</kbd> key, <kbd>⌘</kbd> key is positioned where <kbd>Alt</kbd> is on Windows keyboards.

So I would rephrase the question:

-- How can I switch between language input sources using <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> on Catalina?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcKgn.png is this not available there ?

Comment: @ankii Have you tried it?  I am pretty sure Apple does not let you use alt-shift as a shortcut for anything.  You have to use Karabiner or another app.

Comment: Have you already tried everything at  https://superuser.com/questions/91980/alt-shift-as-language-switch-on-os-x

Comment: Another place which may help:   https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/283201/toggle-language-by-pressing-shift-command

Comment: @TomGewecke I had high hopes for the ⌘+e remapping trick from [there](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/308900/361230) but even this one does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Punto Switcher works. Unfortunately, its main job is automagically converting Russian to English and back, and the UI is, AFAICS, only in Russian.

Still, it can map <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to input source switcher.

Comment: I use [CommandShift](https://github.com/VasylBaran/CommandShift). It's a free and open-source app which allows you to change input source using Command + Shift